# Best way to automate extrinsic submissions for testing

Tags: rpc, testing

I am developing a chain in substrate, and am trying to find the best way to run integration tests against certain sets of extrinsic submissions when the network is running in development mode. It's largely for the purpose of testing external code that communicates with the chain via RPC calls, which is why I cannot use the built-in unit tests.

Is there an existing framework for doing this other than just writing a little script using the javascript or python libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/paritytech/parachains-integration-tests

You can easily send RPC call with that tool